# How do you create a notification content extension without using a storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios10

I want to create a Notification Content Extension to take advantage of the new iOS 10 rich notifications.  However, in the main application we do not make use of interface builder.  How can I create a content extension that does not utilize a story board?

Answer (score 20):

1. Create the Notification Content extension target as you normally would.
2. Remove the storyboard file from the project
3. Remove the **NSExtensionMainStoryboard** entry from the extension's Info.plist.
4. Add a new entry of **NSExtensionPrincipalClass** to the Info.plist under **NSExtension**.  The value should be the 
   namespace of your extension and the class of the main ViewController.  For example, if your extension is called **Pretty Notification** and the class is **PrettyNotificationViewController**, you would enter **Pretty_Notification.PrettyNotificationViewController**.

Note: Your principal class must conform to **UNNotificationContentExtension**

Comment: To build upon this, you'll also need to implement a view in your viewController:     `override func loadView() {
        self.view = UIView(frame: .zero)
}`

Comment: @JustinVallely There is no need to override `loadView()`, as I see.

Comment: When using objc, `PrettyNotificationViewController` is ok, and `Pretty_Notification.PrettyNotificationViewController` causes app extension crash.