# How do I create a UNNotificationContentExtension without a Storyboard?

Tags: ios, push-notification, ios-app-extension

Adding content extension to my app's notification handling. I have it working, but I want to do it without a storyboard directly specified. The reason is that I want the ability to pass this on to a 3rd party framework (that I'm developing) to handle presenting the notification and managing the user response.

I tried removing the `NSExtensionMainStoryboard` entry and adding an `NSExtensionPrincipalClass` entry so I can load the view in code.  However, my class isn't being instantiated. Here's the class definition:

```
class NotificationViewController: NSObject, UNNotificationContentExtension {
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("extension instantiated")
    }

    func didReceive(_ notification: UNNotification) {
        print("notification received")
    }
}
```

Here's my NSExtension entry:

```
<dict>
    <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionDefaultContentHidden</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionCategory</key>
        <string>Messaging</string>
        <key>UNNotificationExtensionInitialContentSizeRatio</key>
        <real>1</real>
    </dict>
    <key>NSExtensionPrincipalClass</key>
    <string>NotificationViewController</string>
    <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.apple.usernotifications.content-extension</string>
</dict>
```

Has anyone done this for content extensions?

Answer (score 3):

Per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39882189/293215), I think you are missing a module prefix in your `NSExtensionPrincipalClass`:

> The value should be the  namespace of your extension and the class of
>   the main ViewController.  For example, if your extension is called
>   **Pretty Notification** and the class is **PrettyNotificationViewController**, you would enter **Pretty_Notification.PrettyNotificationViewController**.

Comment: needed bc the class written in swift.